# How to tune this Amazon Athena SQL query that already uses Parquet files

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have some huge data files in S3 and I am trying to run them using Athena. Right now the query takes about a min but data scanned is in TB's.

Is there a way we can reduce the data to be scanned.

What we tried: we are already trying to compress the underlying files in S3 using parquet format to save costs.

And we are selecting only the columns we need. Is there anything that can be done at query level?

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         A.roll_no, A.name, 
         C.desc, 
         B.grade_number,
         D.hobbies
         SUM(A.total_marks) AS total_marks
     FROM A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.roll_no = A.roll_no 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON C.roll_no = A.roll_no
     LEFT JOIN  
        (SELECT distinct roll_no, hobbies
         FROM D1) AS D ON A.roll_no = D.roll_no 
                       AND A.enrolldate = D.enrolldate
     WHERE B.class = '10' 
       AND B.subject IN ('0001','0002') 
       AND B.category = 'STATE'  
     GROUP BY  A.roll_no, A.name, C.desc,  B.grade_number, D.hobbies
     ORDER BY  A.class_date DESC) 
WHERE 
    A.country_code = 3
    AND C.state_code = 12
    AND B.class_code = 12 
ORDER BY 
    A.class_date DESC;
```

Can some conditions in the where clause be pushed before the join, or is there something else also possible to optimize this query?

Comment: Please post DDL and EXPLAIN - without those, we're just guessing....

Comment: Change the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s.  Your `WHERE` clauses is undoing it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could probably start by putting the final `WHERE` statements inside the SELECT, since it would reduce the number of rows accessed. In fact, this means that you can remove the whole `SELECT *` part of the query and just make it a single query without a sub-select.
- Why is there an `ORDER BY` within the `LEFT JOIN` -- it doesn't seem to be required.
- The `SELECT DISTINCT` is probably costing a lot, so it would be good if this could be avoided/simplified.

<s>Check the `EXPLAIN` Plan to discover the highest costs for the query.</s>

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is unfortunately not available in Athena.

Comment: D'oh! You're right, I never realised. From [Considerations and Limitations for SQL Queries in Amazon Athena - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html): _"EXPLAIN statements are not supported."_